# Update QTreeView when changing a model

Tags: qt, qtreeview

I'm working on a project where I have composite items that can contain simple items. The programm is written using Qt. So I have a tree. I decided to use a composite design pattern.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/composite-design-pattern/

And now I'm trying to show this hierarchy in QTreeView. Let's say I have a `BaseUnit` class. And a `CompositeUnit` class that inherits my `BaseUnit`  class.  So a `CompositeUnit` instance has children which is stored like this: `QVector< BaseUnit* > children`. Also I have a treeModel. In it's constructor I pass a pointer to the root item:

```
TreeModel::TreeModel(BaseUnit* rootItem, QObject *parent):
    QAbstractItemModel(parent),
    rootItem(rootItem)
{

}
```

Then I create my model and pass it to `QTreeView`:

```
 scenario = new CompositeUnit();
 TreeModel* model = new TreeModel(scenario, this);
 ui->treeView->setModel(model);
```

After that I populate `scenario` with children calling it's function:

```
 void BaseUnit::addUnit(BaseUnit *unit)
{
    children.append(unit);
}

...

scenario->addUnit(new BaseUnit(Params params));
```

If I do this part of code before setting the model to the view everything is fine and I see all parents and children. But I need to populate `scenario` after setting the model to the view. So as far as I can understand when I `addUnit` the model  doesn't know about the changes... Am I wrong? Or only the view doesn't know that smth changed in the model? I'm a little bit complicated with this situation. I guess my architecture might be mistaken from the very beginning and I should have implemented it any other way.  Can you give me a clue? Thank you in advance!

Comment: _the model doesn't know about the changes... Am I wrong?_ No, that's exactly your problem. Please, research about [`QAbstractItemModel::beginInsertRows()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#beginInsertRows) and it's companions `endInsertRows()`, `beginRemoveRows()`, `endRemoveRows()`, `beginMoveRows()`, `endMoveRows()`. That's your missing piece.

Comment: There is an encompassing intro to Model View concept, which (near the bottom) has a section about this: [Resizable Models](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#resizable-models). (The title is IMHO a little bit mis-leading.)

Comment: I also found [Address Book Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-addressbook-example.html). Have a look for `TableModel::insertRows()`.

Comment: @Scheff  First, thank you for the answer and the links that you gave. But still I'm a little bit stuck with my problem. Address Book example inserts new row like this contacts.insert(position, { QString(), QString() }); . So they put an empty item, after that as far as I understand they use setData to set the necessary values. But they have QString elements which are able to pass through QVariant. But I have BaseUnit* elements... How to pass them through QVariant?...Maybe I again missunderstand smth. Thank you!

Comment: When the model has been changed, it has to inform the view(s) about this. That's for what the `begin` and `end` functions are good for. The address book sample demonstrates this in its `TableModel::insertRows()`. Actually, it doesn't need to be (named) `insertRows()`, but changes in model should be wrapped in the resp. begin and end function calls to keep the (all) view(s) in sync.